# drag and drop in JSF without using Frameworks

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, drag-and-drop, draggable

I would like to make my JSF application having a drag and drop function between different elements in the lists.

I applied a basic tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) to make the drag and drop function, so then I have something like:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
                style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list1}" var="item">
            <p id="drag_#{item.name}" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)">#{item.name} top</p>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
                style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list2}" var="item">
            <p id="drag_#{item.name}" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)">#{item.name}</p>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

and my script:

```
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>
```

In the div1 I have a list of items coming from the list1, similarly in div2 I have list of items coming from list2. I want to drag and drop the items from div1 into div2 and vice versa. It worked fine, but the new items are still not added to the list in the bean behind it. Can anyone help me how can I do that - adding the dropped item to the list in the bean. Is it possible to do it without using other external frameworks like Richfaces or Primefaces? Thank you all in advanced!

Comment: By doing some ajax...!!! Like existing good frameworks. Effectively this has nothing to do with drag-drop but 'How do  I send client-side events to a server' Or better: 'How do I call a server side method from javascript'. Learn to generalize problems.

Comment: ok thanks for your tip @Kukeltje

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: Unfortunately not, I found that might be so complicated to call the backing beans from javascript, therefore I am looking for another solution, maybe create own JSF drag&drop composite component.

Comment: Not difficult at all: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript